# Python 2: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '40.0'

Tags: python, math, python-2.7

I have a few variables, `x`, `y` and `result`:

```
>>>x = 40
>>>y = 45
>>>result = x / y * 100
>>>result
0
```

So `result == 0`. I know `result == 0`, because I had to print `x = 40.0` instead of print `x = 40`.

But anyway I need it to print out:

```
88.88888888888889
```

How can I do that?

**Note:** I can't just write `x = 40.0`?

And also I have tried to do this like this:

```
x1 = str(x) + '.0'
result = int(x1) / y * 100
```

But Python give me an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '40.0'
```

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> x = 40
>>> y = 45
>>> result = x / y * 100
>>> result
88.88888888888889
```

In Python 2.7, `/` with integer arguments performs [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). You can change this to use standard division with the import as shown.

Alternatively (if you don't want the behavior of `/` to be altered in this way), you can make one of the division arguments a float: `float(x) / y * 100`.